# Understanding Constants of Motion and the dimension of the effective Space available

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, integrable-systems

I'm currently learning about Integrable Hamiltonian Systems and Constants of Motion. In my notes, there is this passage:

> "With each Constant of Motion, the dimension of the effective space available to the orbits is reduced by one".

I also found this on Wikipedia:

> "Constants of motion are useful because they allow properties of the motion to be derived without solving the equations of motion. In fortunate cases, even the trajectory of the motion can be derived as the intersection of isosurfaces corresponding to the constants of motion."

I understand that when you fix the value of a CoM, then you are restricted to a surface which is constant in the $(q,p)$ coordinate system that you use. What I don't understand is why when you fix the value of 2 CoMs, then you only "care" about the intersection of the 2 surfaces when trying to determine the trajectory. Any ideas?

Sorry if I am explaining this in a wrong way, I am not sure I understand everything.

Comment: Which Wikipedia page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you are interested in calculating trajectories. By definition, trajectories lie in CoM’s level sets. So when you have multiple CoM’s, trajectories lie in the intersection of their level sets. For one CoM, the level set is typically a hypersurface. The independence of CoM’s means that the hypersurfaces are transverse.

Take for example the isotropic 2D harmonic oscillator. In the phase space $\mathbb R^4$, the Hamiltonian is:
$$
H=\frac{p^2+q^2+x^2+y^2}{2}
$$
giving the equations of motion:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot x &= p & \dot p &= -x \\
\dot y &= q & \dot q &= -y
\end{align}
$$
You can check that you have three independent equations of motion:
$$
I = \frac{p^2+x^2}{2} \\
J = \frac{q^2+y^2}{2} \\
L_z = xq-yp
$$
The intersection of three such level sets is precisely a trajectory (a circle), each additional intersection with a level set decreases the dimension of the intersection by $1$.

Btw, when trajectories are precisely the intersection of $2d-1$ CoM’s ($2d$ the dimension of phase space), the system is said to be super-integrable. This is rather rare, another famous example is the Kepler problem.

Hope this helps.